# Relative Asset URL

Tags: templating

I'm looking to output the relative URL of my assets instead of the full URL with domain for my Imgix config. As imgix puts it in their docs:

```
http://www.yourcompany.imgix.com/images/examples/pic.jpg
```

Currently, my assets are rendering like so:

```
http://www.yourcompany.imgix.com/http://www.localmachine/images/examples/pic.jpg
```

Looking at this as my code:

```
https://domain.imgix.net/{{ image.FeaturedImage[0].url }}
```

Is there a way to just output a relative URL instead of absolute? (I've looked at plugins for imgix, but seems a bit overkill if it just needs a relative URL?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{{ image.FeaturedImage[0].path }}` may be what you are looking for, this will give you the folder and the filename of an asset.